# Chartjs draw not all data

Tags: canvas, charts, html5-canvas, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I need to show 127 bars but ChartJs display only 6 labels and all bars. How to increase bar height and make it more readable?
I can't set fixed height to canvas because the chart can draw 1, 10, or 150 bars, it depends on received data.
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-smoke-4myvw?file=/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to add the `height` prop to the chart:

```
const BAR_HEIGHT = 23;

export function App() {
  return <Bar options={options} data={data} height={BAR_HEIGHT * data.labels.length} />;
}
```